# Joomla redirect to specific page if not login

Tags: redirect, joomla, authentication, joomla3.0

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I have a website based on Joomla 3.0

I am trying to get all non-log-in users (aka guest/visitor) redirected to a specific joomla menu item when they visit my website.

Example :

website.com - is default joomla menu item and website homepage

webiste.com/redirect - is joomla menu and website page where I want guest to be redirect automaticaly

Once log-in, the user is redirected to homepage (website.com).

I see tons of Joomla plugins for redirect AFTER loging, but nothing for before loging.

Any idea, maybe some simple php ?

Thank you very much !

B.

Answer (score 3):

You can try following Code for redirect login page.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
if($user->id > 0){


JFactory::getApplication()->redirect('registered user url', $error, 'error' );
}
else{
JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(JURI::base().'index.php?option=com_users&view=login', $error, 'error' ); //redirect to login page
}
```

It work for me. I hope it will also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
if($user->id > 0){

$mainframe->redirect('logged in users url here','message','message type');//last param info,error,success etc
}
else{
$mainframe->redirect('not logged in users url here','message','message type');
}
```

Hope its helps.